# Can *args be given after supplying keyword arguments?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

**I'm trying to override a function by supplying all the positional and non positional arguments first, and then supplying the rest of the non keyword argument later.**

Here's the function with the steps taken:

```py
def foo(a, b, c=3, *args, **kwargs):
    print(f"Positional: a={a} | b={b} | c={c}")
    print("*args", args)
    print("**kwargs", kwargs)

from functools import partial

# a partial callable to supply *args later 
part = partial(foo, a=2, b=4, c=3, extra=3)

# Here, I expect that the extra arguments would be called
# but instead raises TypeError
part('a', 'b', 'c')
```

But an error was raised instead.

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-bf0b47424a01> in <module>()
     11 # Here, I expect that the extra arguments would be called
     12 # but instread raises TypeError
---> 13 part('a', 'b', 'c')

TypeError: foo() got multiple values for argument 'a'
```

Is there any solution to this problem without delving into reading it's
signature of the callable (eg. using `inspect.signature` etc.)?

**EDIT:**

Here is the real problem code with Traceback:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


def _builder(parent, label, wtype, *args, **kwargs):
    """
    Function to build widgets for configbox.
    """
    # creae a container frame with the parent
    container = ttk.Frame(parent)
    container.pack(fill='x')

    # add the elements in the container
    # =================================
    # pack label
    label = ttk.Label(container, text=label)
    label.pack(side='left', padx=4, pady=4, fill='x')

    # get the widget by name and instantiate
    # (fails here)
    widget = getattr(ttk, wtype)(container, *args, **kwargs)

    # pack and return
    widget.pack(side='right', padx=4, pady=4, fill='x')
    return widget


class _ConfigBox(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)

        lframe = ttk.Labelframe(self, text="Configurations")
        lframe.pack()

        # this does not fail - (no *args or **kwargs)
        # place extension entry box
        ext_entry = _builder(lframe, "Extension", "Entry")

        # THIS PART FAILS!
        # bind backend variable with option menu
        bkndvar = tk.StringVar(lframe, value="# XXX TEST")
        bknd_opts = _builder(
            lframe,
            "Backend",
            "OptionMenu",

            # give the *args...
            *("TEST1", "TEST2"),

            # ...and the **kwargs (fails here)
            **dict(variable=bkndvar, default=bkndvar.get()),
        )
```

The Traceback:

```py
>>> x = _ConfigBox(tk.Tk())
>>> x.mainloop()

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-d0fface65de6> in <module>()
----> 1 x = _ConfigBox(tk.Tk())
      2 x.mainloop()

<ipython-input-6-aad9dde31798> in __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
     45 
     46             # ...and the **kwargs (fails here)
---> 47             **dict(variable=bkndvar, default=bkndvar.get()),
     48         )

<ipython-input-6-aad9dde31798> in _builder(parent, label, wtype, *args, **kwargs)
     15     # get the widget by name and instantiate
     16     # (fails here)
---> 17     widget = getattr(ttk, wtype)(container, *args, **kwargs)
     18 
     19     # pack and return

TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for argument 'variable'
```

Comment: Note that the error you encounter would be the same when calling ``foo('a', 'b', 'c', a=2, b=4, c=3, extra=3)``. Is there a reason why you want to supply ``a``, `b` and `c` by keywords?

Comment: It is related to `tkinter`. To be less verbose, I presented a simpler situation. In tkinter, i wanted to create a builder function where I can simply supply the name of the object and pass on the rest of the arguments as keywords, but not every tkinter object have same call signature, and some take *args (eg `OptionMenu`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`partial` doesn't match its keyword arguments to the named parameters of the function it wraps; it just saves them to be added to the arguments the `partial` object receives later. That is, `part(foo, a=2, b=4, c=3, extra=3)('a', 'b', 'c')` is exactly equivalent to `foo('a', 'b', 'c', a=2, b=4, c=3, extra=3)`.

You need to pass positional arguments to the call to `partial`.

```
part = partial(foo, 2, 4, 3, extra=3)
```

Then you'll get the result you are looking for:

```
>>> part('a', 'b', 'c')
Positional: a=2 | b=4 | c=3
*args ('a', 'b', 'c')
**kwargs {'extra': 3}
```

Comment: In the context of my work, I have no idea of the call signature of the incoming callable, hence I wanted to be as flexible as possible.

Comment: That's a problem: how do you expect to call a function whose signature you don't know?

Comment: It was related to `tkinter`. The tkinter Objects have different signatures, but I want to simplify the creation of tk widgets just by creating a function which would take the name of tkinter object and the rest of it's arguments. Do I have to delve deeper by creating a decorator or by using `inspect.signature`?

Comment: Your question should have included your real use case from the beginning.

Comment: that would be extremely verbose, and the case I tried to show here was similar to that.

Comment: Verbose or not, it's the question you really want an answer to, and it's not clear exactly how you are using `partial` to solve the problem of defining a single function to instantiate  an arbitrary widget.

Comment: Okay, let me frame the real problem.